# Encryption issue in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing an API for my web application. In my API i am connecting the same database that has been used in my web application. I need to encrypt and compare the password in my API with the password which is already present in my db in an encrypted format. Now since i am new to this project the problem is i don't know how the password was encrypted while storing it in db earlier, so what format do i use to encrypt my password in API. 
Earlier the function which was used to encrypt the password was something like this:

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal input() As Byte) As Byte()
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Dim iLen As Integer = input.Length
  Dim output(0) As Byte
  Dim newInput() As Byte
  Dim inBuffer(BlockSize - 1) As Byte
  Dim buffer(BlockSize - 1) As Byte
  Dim count As Integer = 0
  Try
     count = GetArraySize(input.Length)
     output = New Byte(count- 1) {}
     newInput - New Byte(count - 1) {}
     System.Array.copy(input, 0, newInput, 0, input.Length)
     For i = 0 To count - BlockSize 
         System.Array.Copy(newInput, i, inBuffer, 0, BlockSize)
         System.Array.copy(Cipher(inBuffer), 0, output, i, Blocksize)
     Next i
   Catch excep As Exception
      Throw
   End Try
   Return output
End Function


Private Function Cipher(ByVal input() As Byte) As Byte()

Dim buffer1 As Byte() = New Byte(16 - 1) {}
Try
    Me.State = New Byte(4 - 1, Me.Nb - 1) {}
    Dim num1 As Integer
    For num1 = 0 To (4 * Me.Nb) - 1
        Me.State((num1 Mod 4), Int(num1 / 4)) = input(num1)
    Next num1
    Me.AddRoundKey(0)
    Dim num2 As Integer = 1
    Do While (num2 <= (Me.Nr - 1))
        Me.SubBytes()
        Me.ShiftRows()
        Me.MixColumns()
        Me.AddRoundKeys(num2)
        num2 +=1
     Loop
     Me.SubBytes()
     Me.ShiftRows()
     Me.AddRoundKey(Me.Nr)
     Dim num3 As Integer
     For num3 = 0 To (4 * Me.Nb) - 1
         buffer1(num3) = Me.State((num3 Mod 4), Int(num3 / 4))
     Next num3

  Catch exception As Exception
      Throw
  End Try
  Return buffer1
End Function
```

Also previously the code was in VB.NET and my API is API with MVC.

Comment: Why are you encrypting passwords? You should not be doing this. Read [this](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/) if you want a good reason why not. If you're encrypting AFTER hashing, disregard my comment. If you _are_ storing passwords encrypted, and not hashed. You should immediately change to using password hashing and retrospectively hash existing passwords.

Comment: @john - Sir if i don't  encrypt my text password, how will i compare it with the encrypted password that is stored in my db. Please correct me if i am wrong. I need to move ahead with my login page.

Comment: Read [here](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) to learn about hashing. A hash of a given value will return the same hash value every time. You hash a password with a salt value, and store the hashed password and salt. When a user logs in, you hash the password they provide with the salt you used for the stored password. Then you can compare the stored hash with the computed hash. If they match, the password is correct. This is a simple version, but I'm sure you appreciate the idea.

Comment: @TausifKhan ever heard of hashing passwords and then verify if its correct? Check out libsodium for .NET for a easy and secure implementation.

Comment: You don't need to know or retrieve the user's plaintext password for any reason. The only time you need access to that password is immediately before you hash it.

Comment: Seeing your edit: if your heart is truly set on opening yourself up to a huge security risk, and the loss of trust from your customers (or indeed business) when such an avoidable security breach occurs, then you should at least provide all of the required functions for the encryption method (or the decryption method, if there is one), and what you've done to try and implement the decrypt method in C#.

Comment: @john: This is my company's existing and in working code. I am hired to develop a API for their web application project. i have no rights to touch their existing code. Can you please help me with my issue. Now i just want to compare my text password with the encrypted db password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood,

If your migrate your project from Vb to C# Web API and
your database is still same.

then you face one problem that how can you code to decrypt password in c# where its already encrypted in vb or vice versa.

Means you want a same encryption or decryption algorithm in c# that you used in Vb.

So for this

Here i added C# equivalent code for your vb encrypt and cipher method that your added in your question

1) For Encryption

```
//Encrypt

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input)
{
    int i = 0;
    int iLen = input.Length;
    byte[] output = new byte[1];
    byte[] newInput;
    byte[] inBuffer = new byte[BlockSize - 1 + 1];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BlockSize - 1 + 1];
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        count = GetArraySize(input.Length);
        output = new byte[count - 1 + 1];
        newInput[-new byte[count - 1 + 1]];
        System.Array.copy(input, 0, newInput, 0, input.Length);
        for (i = 0; i <= count - BlockSize; i++)
        {
            System.Array.Copy(newInput, i, inBuffer, 0, BlockSize);
            System.Array.copy(Cipher(inBuffer), 0, output, i, Blocksize);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return output;
}
```

2) For Cypher

```
//Cypher

private byte[] Cipher(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[16] { };
    try
    {
        this.State = new byte[4, this.Nb - 1 + 1];
        int num1;
        for (num1 = 0; num1 <= (4 * this.Nb) - 1; num1++)
            this.State((num1 % 4), Conversion.Int(num1 / (double)4)) = input[num1];
        this.AddRoundKey(0);
        int num2 = 1;
        while ((num2 <= (this.Nr - 1)))
        {
            this.SubBytes();
            this.ShiftRows();
            this.MixColumns();
            this.AddRoundKeys(num2);
            num2 += 1;
        }
        this.SubBytes();
        this.ShiftRows();
        this.AddRoundKey(this.Nr);
        int num3;
        for (num3 = 0; num3 <= (4 * this.Nb) - 1; num3++)
            buffer1[num3] = this.State((num3 % 4), Conversion.Int(num3 / (double)4));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return buffer1;
}
```

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @Tausif Khan, Please check answer, If it helps then vote up and accept answer :)